# How can i change File attachment button to a reset button which send a message "Reset"

Tags: reactjs, botframework

Customise Build BotFramework in react app. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/v3

I have added chatbot in my website using Botframework WebChat V3.

[image: chatbot]

I want to replace the file attachment button with a reset button and send a Message Reset on click.

Comment: To do this, I believe you'd need to clone the webchat repo from GitHub and edit files in the `src` folder. The one you're after is probably `/src/Attachment.tsx`. Is this something you're trying to do? If so, could you share the specific area of the code you need help with?

Comment: Note, the screen shot you posted is [Web Chat v4](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-webchat).

Comment: Do you want the button to clear the conversation transcript and start a new conversation?

Comment: Also, are you using the Web Chat CDN or the npm package?